# How to properly position a CATransformLayer in its super layer

Tags: iphone, catransformlayer

I have created on a `UIView` named containerView which spans the whole screen.On this view a `CATransormLayer` and a UIView have to be added that have the following dimensions.

```
CATransformlayer : doubleSidedLayer  
Height = containerView.frame.size.height  
Width = containerView.frame.size.width  

UIView : stripView
Height = containerView.frame.size.height  
Width = 20;
```

The x position for both of them is specified by the variable positionX. Theoritcally for both `DoubleSidedLayer` and `stripView` must overlapp. But they are not.

Here is the code.

```
CGRect containerFrame =CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.height,self.view.frame.size.width);
NSLog(@"container frame = %f %f %f %f",containerFrame.origin.x,containerFrame.origin.y,containerFrame.size.width,containerFrame.size.height);
UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:containerFrame];
[containerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

float positionX = containerFrame.size.width/4;//This is the position where the stripView and doubleSidedLayer must be placed

//Configuration of CATransformLayer.
CGRect doubleLayerFrame = CGRectMake(positionX,0,containerFrame.size.width/2,containerFrame.size.height);
CATransformLayer *doubleSidedLayer  = [CATransformLayer layer];
[doubleSidedLayer setFrame:doubleLayerFrame];

NSLog(@"DoubleSidedLayer frame = %f %f %f %f",doubleSidedLayer.frame.origin.x,doubleSidedLayer.frame.origin.y,doubleSidedLayer.frame.size.width,doubleSidedLayer.frame.size.height);
NSLog(@"DoubleSidedLayer bounds = %f %f %f %f",doubleSidedLayer.bounds.origin.x,doubleSidedLayer.bounds.origin.y,doubleSidedLayer.bounds.size.width,doubleSidedLayer.bounds.size.height);
NSLog(@"Anchor Points = %f %f",doubleSidedLayer.anchorPoint.x, doubleSidedLayer.anchorPoint.y);
NSLog(@"position = %f %f",doubleSidedLayer.position.x,doubleSidedLayer.position.y);

//Configuring top layer
CALayer *topLayer = [[CALayer alloc]init];
[topLayer setFrame:doubleLayerFrame];
[topLayer setContents:(id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"].CGImage];
[topLayer setZPosition:2];
[topLayer setDoubleSided:NO];

//Adding the layers
[doubleSidedLayer addSublayer:topLayer];
[containerView.layer addSublayer:doubleSidedLayer];

//Adding the stripView
UIView *stripView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(positionX, 0, 20,containerView.frame.size.height)];
[stripView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor cyanColor]];
[containerView addSubview:stripView];
NSLog(@"Strip frame = %f %f %f %f",stripView.frame.origin.x,stripView.frame.origin.y,stripView.frame.size.width,stripView.frame.size.height);

//Adding the containerView to the main view
[self.view addSubview:containerView];
```

From the log statements you can see the frames of doubleSidedLayer and stripView.

```
doubleSidedLayer frame = 120.000000 0.000000 240.000000 300.000000   
strip frame = 120.000000 0.000000 20.000000 300.000000
```

But both of them do not overlap. Here is the screenshot.[image]

Note : I am working in landscape orientation.

Comment: Can you describe what user experience you're trying to achieve? You've jumped into a lot of `CALayer` detail, but if you want to get an effect of being able to flip from one subview to another, rather than trying to diagnose your above code, I might suggest you use `transitionWithView` like my example below. But if you're trying to achieve some other effect, let us know what you're trying to do. Personally, I'd rather understand what you're trying to achieve and find the best way to do that, rather than trying to figure out what's going on with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wonder if there's an easier way to achieve what you're looking for. For example, if I have some view where I want to "flip" an image from one image to another, I use something like the following:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.imageView
                  duration:0.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                animations:^{
                    if (self.flipped)
                        self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"front.png"];
                    else
                        self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];

                    self.flipped = !self.flipped;

                }
                completion:nil];
```

I'm doing this with an imageview, but the concept works the same for whatever `UIView` controls you use. If you have some container view and you want to add/remove or show/hide controls in this `animations` block, you can do that, too. Just use the container view for the first parameter of the `transitionWithView`.

Comment: But I want some more control on this. By this method, we do not have control on the axis of rotation.Therefore I am using CATransformLayer.

Comment: Thank you Rob for your response. I was able to get the desired effect. But I have a conceptual doubt about CATransformLayer. So I am modifying the question.

Answer (score 0):

I could figure out my mistake. There was problem in configuration of topLayer. This should be fit within the bounds of `doubleSidedLayer`. So I changed `[topLayer setFrame:doubleLayerFrame]` to `[topLayer setFrame:doubleSidedLayer.bounds]`. This fixed my issue.